# Parsing with Jsoup, only gets default value

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm parsing a webpage with Jsoup which so far is going good, except that when I parse, I get the data that's the 'default text', the text displayed right before a javascript changes the value.

There's

`<span id="p1name" class="redtext">Player 1</span>`

which I can parse with

```
Element player1Div = doc.getElementById("p1name");
p1name = player1Div.text();
player1.setText(p1name);
```

Then there's a script on the website

```
    <script>

                    $(document).ready(function() {
            getData();
            });
            function getData() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
                    url: '../data.json',
                    data: '',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                    player1name = data['p1name'];
                    $("#p1name").text(player1name);
</script>
```

which changes the element's text. So I thought I could just run the java code again and get the new text, but that won't work as I keep getting "Player 1" (whereas I'm sure it should display a different string)

What are my options? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[`JSoup`](http://jsoup.org/) can't solve your problem. All `Jsoup` knows is *parse* and *extract* the data.

As the desired text is not part of the `html` during the parsing  it can't be extracted from the `Document`

All you can do is, issue a new request to `../data.json` and fetch the data. Provided, you know that url before fetching the content.